# How to enter ':norm ' in function

Tags: vim

I want to select textobject linewise and after that I want preentered `:norm` in command line that will wait for my further orders

```
function! s:SelectAndEnterNorm(...)
  " I am selecting textobject that was entered after ,.
  silent exe "normal! '[V']"

  " and now I want that the string ":norm " was entered 
  " in command line as if I entered it
  " I have tried this but it doesnt work, without errors
  silent exe "normal! :norm"
endfunction

nmap <silent> <leader>. :set opfunc=<SID>SelectAndEnterNorm<CR>g@

" same with visual mode
vnoremap <leader>. :norm<space>
```

And

Comment: `normal! :norm` are you ware that `norm` is the shortcut of `normal` ?

Comment: I'm guessing you could use `feedkeys` here but I can't test at the moment.  Generally `feedkeys` isn't what you want long term though so I'm sure there is a better solution.

Comment: Oh yes, feedkeys has worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Randy Morris

```
function! s:SelectAndEnterNorm(...)
  silent exe "normal! '[V']"
  call feedkeys(":norm ")
endfunction

vnoremap <leader>. :norm<space>
nmap <silent> <leader>. :set opfunc=<SID>SelectAndEnterNorm<CR>g@
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer (once you are able to) since you've solved your issue.